# Jquery fetching parent of previously used element

Tags: jquery, parent

I'm creating a full editable menus and stuck with one weird problem. I made script for editing menu button text, it hides link and appends input to div. Here's the code:

```
$('#edit_button').click(function() {
        var temp = id;
        $("#" + temp + " a").hide("fast", function(){
            if($("#link_editor").length > 0){
                var temp_id = $("#link_editor").parent().attr("id");
                $("#link_editor").hide("fast", function(){
                    $("#link_editor").remove();
                    $("#" + temp_id + " a").show("fast");
                });
            }
            $("<input type='text' id='link_editor' value='" + $("#" + temp + " a").html() + "'>").hide().appendTo("#" + temp).show("fast");
        });
    });
```

Menu looks like this => Home Blog Contact
So when I click first on Home, then on Blog, etc - everything works perfect, but if I start from Contacts and go back it doesn't work. You can see live example [here](http://temporaryaddress.hopto.org/). Just mouse over any menu button and click on edit icon. Global id is received on mouse over.

Here's menu code:

```
<div id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
        <div id="0"><a href="?page=Home" id="0" class="prevent_doubleclick" title="" style="display: block; ">Home</a></div>
        <div id="1"><a href="?page=Gallery" id="1" class="prevent_doubleclick" title="" style="display: block; ">Gallery</a></div>
        <div id="2"><a href="?page=Blog" id="2" class="prevent_doubleclick" title="" style="display: block; ">Blog</a></div>
        <div id="3"><a href="?page=About" id="3" class="prevent_doubleclick" title="" style="display: none; ">About</a><input type="text" id="link_editor" value="About" style=""></div>
        <div id="4"><a href="?page=Contact" id="4" class="prevent_doubleclick" title="">Contact</a></div>
    <div class="add_button" style="margin-top: -10px; display: none; "><a style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;"><img src="/img/add.png">Add Button</a></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `$(this).remove().parent().find('a').show('fast');` inside the callback the element is available as `this`, and then it's just a matter of traversing the DOM ?

Comment: Problem is, that I need to remove element which was previously accessed, not that one which is currently build up

Answer (score 0):

I found out answer to my own question. Somehow .remove() function doesn't wait for .hide() function to finish. Maybe there's a better way to solve this issue, but I found it only like this:
Changed this:

```
$("#link_editor").hide("fast", function(){
                    $("#link_editor").remove();
                    $("#" + temp_id + " a").show("fast");
                });
```

To this:

```
                $("#link_editor").remove();
                $("#" + temp_id + " a").show("fast");
```